# fill property of SVG does not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, fill

Trouble is that I can't set value (color) in fill property in Chrome, but in Firefox it works. I tried a lot ways to do it, but there is no result. The only way I see to change color of SVG icon is via jQuery (or JavaScript) by changing id of `<symbol>`, which is below. Please help me solve this problem!

This is what I need to work in Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        span:hover .pathCrossBtn{
            fill: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <svg width="0" height="0" style='display: none;' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 2048 2048" id="crossBtn">
        <path class="pathCrossBtn" fill="red" d="M1618 1450q0 40-28 68l-136     136q-28 28-68 28t-68-28l-294-294-294 294q-28 28-68 28t-68-28l-136-136q-28-28-28-68t28-68l294-294-294-294q-28-28-28-68t28-68l136-136q28-28 68-28t68 28l294 294 294-294q28-28 68-28t68 28l136 136q28 28 28 68t-28 68l-294 294 294 294q28 28 28 68z"/>
    </symbol>
</svg>
<span>
    <svg class="crossBtn" viewBox="0 0 2048 2048" width="30" height="30">
        <use xlink:href="#crossBtn"></use>
    </svg>
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

This is bad way to solve my problem which is not approriate for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <svg width="0" height="0" style='display: none;' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <symbol viewBox="0 0 2048 2048" id="crossBtnBlue">
          <path class="pathCrossBtn" fill="blue" d="M1618 1450q0 40-28 68l-136 136q-28 28-68 28t-68-28l-294-294-294 294q-28 28-68 28t-68-28l-136-136q-28-28-28-68t28-68l294-294-294-294q-28-28-28-68t28-68l136-136q28-28 68-28t68 28l294 294 294-294q28-28 68-28t68 28l136 136q28 28 28 68t-28 68l-294 294 294 294q28 28 28 68z"/>
        </symbol>
        <symbol viewBox="0 0 2048 2048" id="crossBtnRed">
           <path class="pathCrossBtn" fill="red" d="M1618 1450q0 40-28 68l-136 136q-28 28-68 28t-68-28l-294-294-294 294q-28 28-68 28t-68-28l-136-136q-28-28-28-68t28-68l294-294-294-294q-28-28-28-68t28-68l136-136q28-28 68-28t68 28l294 294 294-294q28-28 68-28t68 28l136 136q28 28 28 68t-28 68l-294 294 294 294q28 28 28 68z"/>
        </symbol>
</svg>
<span>
    <svg class="crossBtn" viewBox="0 0 2048 2048" width="30" height="30">
        <use xlink:href="#crossBtnRed"></use>
    </svg>
</span>
<script>
;(function(){
    $('.crossBtn')
        .mouseover(function(){
            $('span svg use').attr('xlink:href','#crossBtnBlue');
        })
        .mouseleave(function(){
            $('span svg use').attr('xlink:href','#crossBtnRed');
        })
}());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @RobertLongson want to make sure I understand: are you saying it's a bug in an svg referenced with `use` because that embedded svg is in the shadow dom?

Comment: @henry Firefox has fixed its implementation to match the SVG 2 spec. Try a nightly and see. I imagine Chrome will align with the SVG 2 spec if it hasn't already.

Comment: @RobertLongson  but I'm still not clear exactly what the "this" in "this is a known bug" is. I've tried looking for a bug ticket but no luck so far.

Comment: @henry https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=265894

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `currentcolor` in the `path` `fill` attribute of the `<symbol>` element.

> The currentcolor keyword represents the value of an element's color
> property. This lets you use the color value on properties that do not
> receive it by default.

Then, add a `color` CSS property to the class of the `<svg>` container that will wrap the `<symbol>` instantiated by the `<use>` element.

```css
.icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.icon--blue {
  color: blue;
}

.icon--red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" style="display: none;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 2048 2048" id="crossBtn">
    <path class="pathCrossBtn" fill="currentcolor" d="M1618 1450q0 40-28 68l-136     136q-28 28-68 28t-68-28l-294-294-294 294q-28 28-68 28t-68-28l-136-136q-28-28-28-68t28-68l294-294-294-294q-28-28-28-68t28-68l136-136q28-28 68-28t68 28l294 294 294-294q28-28 68-28t68 28l136 136q28 28 28 68t-28 68l-294 294 294 294q28 28 28 68z"
    />
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg class="icon icon--red" viewBox="0 0 2048 2048">
  <use xlink:href="#crossBtn"></use>
</svg>
<svg class="icon icon--blue" viewBox="0 0 2048 2048">
  <use xlink:href="#crossBtn"></use>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a generic solution to the problem mentioned above, but I came here for a similar problem, where `fill="none"` on an svg node doesn't seem to work under all circumstances in both Chrome and Firefox, and potentially other browsers. This piece of SCSS fixes it for us, in our case for [feather icons](https://feathericons.com/) rendered via [react-svgr](https://react-svgr.com/):

```
svg:global(.feather) {
    // Fix for `fill="none"` not working properly in (at least) Chrome and Firefox
    // Part 1: If there is a `fill` property, reset `fill-opacity`.
    //         This is for children of elements with `fill="none"`
    &[fill], *[fill] {
        fill-opacity: initial;
    }
    // Part 2: If the element uses `fill="none"`, set `fill-opacity` to 0.
    &[fill='none'], *[fill='none'] {
        fill-opacity: 0;
    }

}
```

The equivalent CSS, for the generic case:

```css
svg[fill], svg *[fill] {
    fill-opacity: initial;
}
svg[fill='none'], svg *[fill='none'] {
    fill-opacity: 0;
}
```

*Note that this may not cover all cases of SVG elements with fill properties and children with differently valued properties, so adapt to your needs.*