# CSS Fill Property On SVG

Tags: html, css, sass, next.js

I'm trying to change an svg's color on hover - this is my code right now:

SVG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.0.2, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 56.7 56.7" enable-background="new 0 0 56.7 56.7" xml:space="preserve" fill="#6c787a">
<g>
    <path d="M28.2,16.7c-7,0-12.8,5.7-12.8,12.8s5.7,12.8,12.8,12.8S41,36.5,41,29.5S35.2,16.7,28.2,16.7z M28.2,37.7
        c-4.5,0-8.2-3.7-8.2-8.2s3.7-8.2,8.2-8.2s8.2,3.7,8.2,8.2S32.7,37.7,28.2,37.7z" fill="#6c787a"/>
    <circle cx="41.5" cy="16.4" r="2.9"/>
    <path d="M49,8.9c-2.6-2.7-6.3-4.1-10.5-4.1H17.9c-8.7,0-14.5,5.8-14.5,14.5v20.5c0,4.3,1.4,8,4.2,10.7c2.7,2.6,6.3,3.9,10.4,3.9
        h20.4c4.3,0,7.9-1.4,10.5-3.9c2.7-2.6,4.1-6.3,4.1-10.6V19.3C53,15.1,51.6,11.5,49,8.9z M48.6,39.9c0,3.1-1.1,5.6-2.9,7.3
        s-4.3,2.6-7.3,2.6H18c-3,0-5.5-0.9-7.3-2.6C8.9,45.4,8,42.9,8,39.8V19.3c0-3,0.9-5.5,2.7-7.3c1.7-1.7,4.3-2.6,7.3-2.6h20.6
        c3,0,5.5,0.9,7.3,2.7c1.7,1.8,2.7,4.3,2.7,7.2V39.9L48.6,39.9z" fill="#6c787a" />
</g>
</svg>
```

JSX (in next.js)

```
import styles from '../styles/Footer.module.scss'
import Image from 'next/image'

const Footer = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <footer className={styles.footer}>
                        <div className={styles.mediaIcons}>
                            <Image
                                src='/images/instagramIcon.svg'
                                alt='Instagram'
                                width={30}
                                height={30}
                                className={styles.mediaIcon}
                            />
                        </div>
            </footer>

        </>
    )
}

export default Footer
```

SCSS (SaSS)

```
.mediaIcon {
            margin-left: 25px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            transition-duration: 0.2s;
        }

.mediaIcon:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        fill: $textColor !important;
}
```

I saw another question about this issue ([SVG Fill Color Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39743161/svg-fill-color-not-working)), the answers suggested to mark the fill property as important in css but it did not work for me. I have been using the filter property to change the color of svg's but it's never 100% accurate in color and the animation looks weird, any better options?

Comment: I don't find a reliable source at the moment but I think the problem is that you can only use inline SVGs to apply CSS styles. It does not work, when you use an `<img>`. This article covers it: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#aa-the-problem-with-both-img-and-background-image

Comment: The problem is that inline SVGs are not supported in React